# IntelliSense unavailable for C++/CLI Visual Studio 2010 - XmlReader/XmlWriter nonmanaged alternative

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, intellisense

I wrote an application which generates an XML file using XmlReader and XmlWriter (with managed code) in Visual Studio 2010 C++, using cli.

Now the problem appears that no IntelliSense is available for C++/CLI.
Is there an alternative for cli? Otherwise, is there an update which enables Intellisense for C++ managed code or an other solution for this problem available/known?

I am looking for an alternative to write and read an XML file using managed code and the XmlReader and XmlWriter! So, something which works without managed code (cli) and supports IntelliSense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) should provide IntelliSense for C++/CLI on dev10, but is not free.

Visual Studio will support it out of the box again in dev11.

Comment: Ah, sorry, for writing and reading an XML file using managed code and the XmlReader and XmlWriter!

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to write and read an XML file using managed code and the XmlReader and XmlWriter! So, something which works without managed code (cli) and supports IntelliSense

Comment: Well, that's another question, but you could use Xerces-C++ or TinyXML.